# How to make UINavigationBar fully transparent or gone like this only title and UIBarButtonItem could be seen

Tags: ios, uitableview, uinavigationbar, uistatusbar

As you can see, the UINavigationBar is fully transparent. Only the title and UIBarButtonItem is visible. And the status bar has the same colour as UITableView's background colour. Right now, I have finished to make the table view and cell has the same effect as the pic. But how to make the navigation bar and the status bar has the effect too?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one

```
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.shadowImage = [UIImage new];
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = YES;
    self.navigationController.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage new] forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this !

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationController.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
```